# passing each element of a list as an argument to a function

Tags: python

I have a list

```
try_list = ["[('aaaa', 34), ('bbbb', 1), ('cccc', 1)]", "[('dddd', 4), ('eeee', 1)]"]
```

Each entry within "" is an element of a list.

When I say

```
for i in try_list:
    print i
```

I get the individual elements,

```
[('aaaa', 34), ('bbbb', 1), ('cccc', 1)]
[('dddd', 4), ('eeee', 1)]
```

But if I try to pass each individual to a function (say func) as

```
for i in try_list:
    item = func(i)
```

I get an error.

If I test the function func with each element, one by one, it works fine so func is fine. So the error is in passing the lists as arguments, one at a time. What is the correct way of doing this?

Here is func:

```
def func(my_list):
    ans = []
    for i,name in enumerate(my_list):
        print name[0],name[1]
        ans.append(name)
    return ans
```

If I say

```
func([('aaaa', 34), ('bbbb', 1), ('cccc', 1)])
```

I get the correct output

```
aaaa 34

bbbb 1

cccc 1

[('aaaa', 34), ('bbbb', 1), ('cccc', 1)]
```

But if I say

```
for i in try_list:
    item = func(i)
```

I get the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "", line 4, in func
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. What is `func`? What is the error you're getting? What's the exact code you're running.

Comment: I have updated my query with complete code which is giving trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite (un)fortunately, the return value of `__repr__` for the list `[('aaaa', 34)]` is the same as the string `"[('aaaa', 34)]"`.

That's why you have `print` outputting something that looks like a list. But what you have is not a list of lists but a list of strings.

---

```
>>> print("[('aaaa', 34)]")
[('aaaa', 34)]
>>>
>>> print([('aaaa', 34)])
[('aaaa', 34)]
```

You probably want to convert your string into a list before passing as parameter to your function.

You can have a look at [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) if you need to *safely* make the conversion from the string you have into a list.